# How to set inbound properties using set message component in Munit Test case

Tags: mule, expression, mel, munit

In one of my munit test case i am trying to set uri parmas using 'Set Message'. 
the key value pair is as showing in below example :

**productcode :('11','10')**

When i try to set this in component i am facing issue with with MEL expression.
Expression with single quot doesn't seems to accept.

Error : 
*org.mule.api.MessagingException: MEL parsing failed. The expression: #[['productcode' :'( ('11','10'))']] is an invalid expression. (org.mule.munit.common.exception.MunitError).*

Below is my Munit test case.

```html
<munit:test name="gl-impl-test-suite-gl-getTransactionDataFromAgresso-Test" description="Test">
        <mock:when messageProcessor=".*:.*" doc:name="mockGetReconciliationDataFromAgresso">
            <mock:with-attributes>
                <mock:with-attribute name="doc:name" whereValue="#['getReconciliationDataFromAgresso']"/>
            </mock:with-attributes>
            <mock:then-return payload="#[getResource('scaffolder/response/emp/getEmployeeDetails.xml').asString()]" mimeType="application/xml"/>
        </mock:when>
        <munit:set payload="#[]" doc:name="Set Message">
            <munit:inbound-properties>
                <munit:inbound-property key="http.query.parmas" value="#[['productcode' :'( ('11','10'))']]"/>
            </munit:inbound-properties>
        </munit:set>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <flow-ref name="gl-getTransactionDataFromAgresso" doc:name="Flow-ref to gl-getTransactionDataFromAgresso"/>
    </munit:test>
```

Please let me know how to set the MEL expression which contains single quot.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"#[[&quot;productcode&quot; :&quot;(('11','10'))&quot;]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by user3366906 will correctly address the issue with the single quotes, alternatively you can escape the single quotes. I generally prefer to use the mixed quotes, but rarely you need both single and double quotes in the string where escaping is useful.

```
value="#[['productcode' :'((\'11\',\'10\'))']]"
```